# Rails post parameters name syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I'm trying to find out the format of the name of the input filed for nested attributes. Let's say that I have a edit action with input fields:

```
<input type="text" name="...">
```

I found out that the syntax for the name of the parameters is:

```
"controller_name[attribute_name]"
```

After a lot of tried I even found out that nested hash parameters can be passed as:

```
"controller_name[attribute_name][attribute_name]"
```

My problem is that I have has_many nested attributes and I didn't managed to find out what syntax rails expecting for array of nested records.
Also it'll be nice to know how can I pass something to say that I want to destroy a nested record.

I'm using Rails 5.1 BTW

Comment: Why don't you use the Rails form helper that generate the expected names for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you use has_many it will have accept_nested_attributes in parent model.

for example

```
Class Book 
  has_many :pages 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages
End
```

so in the view it will be like this

```
<input name="book[pages_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input name="book[pages_attributes][0][name]" type="text" />
<input name="book[pages_attributes][1][id]" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input name="book[pages_attributes][1][name]" type="text" />
```

for destroy you have a hidden input

```
<input name="book[pages_attributes][0][_destroy]" value="true" type="hidden" />
```

this will easily update the Book object and pages when you do

```
@book.update_attributes
```

Comment: Thanks! But what is 0 means? The id? just a number that must be different for each record?
How can I tell Rails to destroy an existing record?

Comment: 0 means first related page object to Book

Comment: updated my answer much better for your understanding

Comment: Did you add allow_destroy in accept nested attributes

Comment: Thanks! You forgot to write it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it goes something like this:

```
<input name="user[posts_attributes][0][id]" value="5" />
<input name="user[posts_attributes][0][body]" value="You've given me too much to feel" />

<input name="user[posts_attributes][1][id]" value="8" />
<input name="user[posts_attributes][1][body]" value="You've almost convinced me I'm real" />
```

Remember to add this to your User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end
```

I normally use SimpleForm to make this a lot easier:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :posts do |f_post| %>
    <%= f_post.input :body %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```